# What is the contribution of group theory to topology?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, soft-question, education

[An answer for a question on MathOverflow.net which asked for some recommendations on textbooks for books in topology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83881/a-book-in-topology/83890#83890) received the following comment:

> "It's a great book to introduce applied topology, although it stops just short of using groups."

1. Pedagogically, what is the value of group theory to topology?
2. How does group theory make strengthen topology as a theory?

Comment: Have you heard of the algebraic topology?

Comment: @janmarqz No. Why don't you tell me about it? I promise to upvote your answer, and accept it too.

Comment: @twirlobite, Algebraic topology is usually an advanced undergraduate-graduate level course, and it uses algebra in topology, and among this it uses **tons** of group theory. Telling you what this is may be a little too long and dry without a proper introduction. Better, try to google "fundamental group", homology/cohomology groups, van Kampen-Seifert Theorem...and check the links there.

Comment: @DonAntonio Could you motivate it perhaps by telling me something cool I couldn't do without it?

Comment: But if you don't know what algebraic topology is then this could be a little frustrating, @twirlobite...anyway, it'd be a rather tough task (if possible at all) to calculate some fundamental groups without the van K-S theorem, using free products with amalgams and stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a concrete example, the usual proof that $\Bbb R^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^m$ if $n \ne m$ requires group theory (some invariant group (the $n$th homology of 'your space') is associated to a topological space and a homeomorphism induces an isomorphism of such groups and $\Bbb R^n-\{0\}$ and $\Bbb R^m-\{pt\}$ have groups that are obviously not isomorphic). These spaces are somehow the most basic and important examples of topological spaces, yet even showing they are not equivalent as topological spaces requires some knowledge of groups.

In general, groups (and other algebraic structures) allow us to define a host of such invariants that allow us to distinguish topological spaces. This is extremely important since we often care more about spaces that are path-connected, Hausdorff and in general nice, so a lot of our tools from basic "point-set topology" of showing two spaces are not homeomorphic are lost. Really the goal of any study of topology is to deduce when two spaces are the same (there are weaker notions of "the same" than homeomorphic) and when they are not, and groups are instrumental in the second case.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! If it is so important to topology though, why does the book in question (Introduction to Topology: Applied and Pure) stop short of groups?

Comment: Perhaps that book is an introductory one, @twirlobite ? BTW, writing the book's title without giving the author doesn't look nice...

Comment: @DonAntonio My apologies! I gave a link to it in my question, but here is another one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/83881/a-book-in-topology/83890#83890

Comment: Oh, the Adams-Franzosa's...I know the book, and in fact I have it. It gets very closely to get into groups in the homotopy thing, but after all it is an introductory text.